# variable safety in unity thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, thread-safety

As far as I know, the variable in thread should be not safe if not locked. But I tried it on Unity, and found it different.
I try the code below:

```
    void Awake () {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart (demo));
        thread.Start ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    void demo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
```

And I try to *Debug.Log(count)*, and every times I try it that is 10000. But it should be a number which is less than 10000 because of not thread safety, shouldn't it? So can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] so that we can copy-paste-and-run your code?

Comment: can you show us the code where you invoke the awake method

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw - We need the full code, not just the call to `.Awake()`. We need a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code:

```
void Main()
{
    Awake();
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}

private int count = 0;

public void Awake()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(demo));
    thread.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    thread.Join();
}

public void demo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

If you run that you get `10000` out. This is because by the time the thread has started the `.Awake()` method has finished its loop and thus no conflict occurs.

Try changing the loops to `for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)` then the result I got for one run is `89922`. It changes each time, but sometimes I still get `100000`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The thread need some time to schedule to start. The main thread might finish the increments before the other thread start. Try to use a large value like 50000000.